# How to calculate the effect sizes for a meta-analysis if a RCT study reported the correlation coefficient using partial pearson corrleation analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, metafor

I am currently performing a meta-analysis focusing on investigating the changes in variable A following weight loss. To address this, I have included studies that provide pre-and post-intervention A levels for both intervention and control groups. This will allow me to calculate the standard mean differences and variance as effect sizes.

However, one study reported correlation coefficients between changes in weight and changes in A levels using partial Pearson correlations adjusted for one confounder.

I am now totally lost regarding calculating the effect size based on these correlation coefficients. Is anyone familiar with the process of calculating such effect sizes using R? Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible to calculate a treatment effect with the information you mentioned. Please, provide more details, with examples.